# Xcode build issue when compiling Flutter project for iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, package

I am trying to build an iOS version of an app.  The app will build to an Android device and I can build the app locally on my iPhone 11 Simulator with Flutter (Android Studio).  I'm trying to build via Xcode to the same simulator.  I get the following error:

:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Here is my pubspect.yaml dependencies.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.19.0
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5+2
  file_picker: any
  soundpool: any
  bubble_tab_indicator: ^0.1.3
  video_player: any
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  googleapis: ^0.52.0+1
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.6
  rx_command: ^4.0.2
  rx_widgets: ^2.2.0
  camera: any
  timeago: any
  flutter_cache_manager: ^0.3.2
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  sentry: ^2.1.1
  device_info: ^0.3.0
  flutter_slidable: any
  url_launcher: ^5.0.3
  logger:
    git: git://github.com/logger-dart/logger.dart.git
  flutter_picker:
    git: git://github.com/yangyxd/flutter_picker.git
  #  audioplayers: ^0.12.0
  flutter_sound: any
  googleapis_beta: ^0.47.0+1
  logging: ^0.11.3+2
  quiver_log: ^1.0.6
  http_auth: ^0.2.3
  #  simple_animations: ^1.1.0
  speech_recognition: any
  package_info: ^0.4.0+4
  graphs: ^0.2.0
  flutter_reorderable_list: ^0.1.3
  provider: ^2.0.1
  image: ^2.1.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.4.0+2
  #  extended_image: ^0.3.5
  flutter_share_me: ^0.2.1
  native_device_orientation: any
  simple_animations: any
  flutter_custom_clippers: any
  polygon_clipper: any
  expandable: any
  reorderables: any
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.2
  built_value: any
  built_collection: any
  get_it: any
  http: any
  validators: ^2.0.0+1
  permission_handler: ^3.2.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  animated_background: any
  webview_flutter: any
  flutter_ffmpeg: any

dependency_overrides:
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
```

What would be the offending dependency or issue that would not allow me to build to the same simulator using Xcode?  Again, the simulator build via Android Studio has no issues.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the edit suggestion

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

make Build Libraries for Distribution is No